# Remove underline from linked images

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm adding custom social media icon links on my website (Wordpress) and there is a stubborn line that runs through them just like hyperlinks. The line disappears when mouse hovers over image, just link other hyperlinks on page.

[image: picture of problem]

This is the code used to create them:

```css
.custom-social img {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-social">
  <a href="http://twitter.com/mrsideproject">
    <img title="Twitter" alt="Twitter" src="http://coinpages.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/twitter-badge.png" width="35" height="35" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://medium.com/@mrsideproject">
    <img title="Medium" alt="Medium" src="http://coinpages.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/medium-logo.png" width="35" height="35" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://instagram.com/mrsideproject">
    <img title="Instagram" alt="Instagram" src="http://coinpages.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Instagram-badge.png" width="29" height="30" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like this line is originated in another element

Answer (score 4):

The `text-decoration` is on the `a`, not the `img`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried it on the 'a' also and no luck but I was able to get rid of the line with 'border:0'. Though I don't really know why.

Comment: In that case, your provided code is not sufficient to catch the border error. As there is no border style.

Comment: Apologies, a lot of styles are inherited from the theme and I'm just adding CSS to modify things so just finding out what styles are being applied is a challenge in itself.

Comment: Not a problem buddy. Glad you were able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Add text decoration in anchor tag. Use Css:

```
.custom-social a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as Daniel said, `text-decoration:none` is supposed on the anchor tag.

```css
.custom-social a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.custom-social img{
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-social">
  <a href="http://twitter.com/mrsideproject">
    <img title="Twitter" alt="Twitter" src="http://coinpages.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/twitter-badge.png" width="35" height="35" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://medium.com/@mrsideproject">
    <img title="Medium" alt="Medium" src="http://coinpages.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/medium-logo.png" width="35" height="35" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://instagram.com/mrsideproject">
    <img title="Instagram" alt="Instagram" src="http://coinpages.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Instagram-badge.png" width="29" height="30" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

OK, I figured it out! not entirely sure why text-decoration wasn't having any effect but this did the trick:

```
.custom-social a {
border:0;
}
```

Comment: Well Daniel provided such answer, didn't he. And if you're still unsure why it happens - well, who has text-decoration by default? Anchors or Images?